# Absolute Positioning In React Native

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native

I am building my first application with react native.
I am trying to create a reusable badge component which is supposed to stand as a notifier or counter for notifications at different parts of my application.
The image below explains more.

[image]

I am trying to achieve the red circle on the top right corner of the speech bubble, to do this I figured I have to position the element to absolute, and I have but only that the element still creates a space in its parent element as though it is relatively postioned while it is still moved to the top right, I hop that was clear?
This is my styling code.

```
style:{
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    right:0,
    top:0
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    backgroundColor:'#ffff00',
    color: '#ffffff',
    borderRadius: 30
}
```

Would love to know what I'm missing here, thanks!

Comment: I found out what caused this, while developing react caches your project for fast reload (I use hot reload). To clear the cache, I had to restart my react native server and add the reset cache option like so `react-native start --reset-cache` it worked after this, a silly mistake I must say. :(

Answer (score 3):

Hope it will help

```
<View style={{position: 'relative'}}>
   <Image /> //CommentIcon
   <View style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0, top: 0, borderRadius: 5, height: 10, width: 10, backgroundColor: '#00ff00'}}>
       <Text> 3 </Text>                    
   </View> 
</View>
```